# How do I keep my address formatted correctly?

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I am trying to put an address in a table in html for an email. I want to make sure my Address displays like this

[image: Screenshot1]

But on some other devices or phones, it will display like this.

[image: Screenshot2]

My code is here

```
<td style="vertical-align: center; background-color:#00693E; width: 100pt; text-align: left; font-size:8;">
        <div style="color:white;">
            Some Name for a Group
            <br>
            1234 Random St
            <br>
            San Francisco, CA 94107
            <br>
            website.com
        </div>
    </td>
```

I don't know how I can keep the address on the right side of a row but not make the text right aligned. I am keeping it in a cell for now and it's the second to last cell from the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue in html email. Firstly, your code should be laid out in 100% tables. I added a wrapper table to demonstrate how to align it right but have the text left aligned. Here is the finished product:

```
<style>
  .appleLinks a {color: #ffffff !important; text-decoration: none;}
</style>

<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="right">
      <table width="100" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td valign="middle" bgcolor="#00693E" style="font-size:8px; color:#FFFFFF;">
            Some Name for a Group
            <br>
            1234&nbsp;Random&nbsp;St
            <br>
            San&nbsp;Francisco,&nbsp;CA&nbsp;94107
            <br>
            <a href="website.com" style="color: #FFFFFE; text-decoration: none;"><span class="appleLinks">website.com</span></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>      
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The address is easy to hide, just put `&nbsp;` in between words to disguise it. The reason it is blue is because your email client is "doing you a favor" by recognizing it and giving you the one-click functionality to call the number, map the address or visit the site etc.

To prevent this, the url is a bit harder, as you can't just stuff `&nbsp;` in there. Check out [this article](https://litmus.com/blog/update-banning-blue-links-on-ios-devices) for more details. The best method it covers is to add something like this to your style tag:

```
.appleLinks a {color: #ffffff !important; text-decoration: none;}
```

and wrap your url with spans:

```
<a href="website.com" style="color: #FFFFFE; text-decoration: none;"><span class="appleLinks">website.com</span></a>
```

I took the liberty of adding the href to your url. You'll notice I used #FFFFFE, which is almost white. This is because Gmail ignores pure white and black (#FFFFFF and #000000 respectively) and defaults to the standard blue link (which we don't want).

Comment: +1 Great Answer. Although why *should* the layout be in tables?  Is this the standard within emails, because it is frowned upon it web dev.

Comment: Tables are more consistent across email clients. They also allow you to use certain html elements, (that are also more consistent) that you can not use in divs. 2 of the main reasons: Outlook uses the MS Word engine to render the email's html, while web clients that need to protect the integrity of their html based page (your email is rendering inside their webpage), strip CSS that could affect it. @KyleMit

Answer (score 0):

1.: Try styling your table td's with element attributes instead of inline styling, like this:

```
<td width="100pt" style="vertical-align: center; background-color:#00693E; text-align: left; font-size:8;">
        <div style="color:white;">
            Some Name for a Group
            <br>
            1234 Random St
            <br>
            San Francisco, CA 94107
            <br>
            website.com
        </div>
    </td>
```

2.: Repeat this procedure to the main table, in order to force a width.

3.: Also try placing an image/other element and styling it like the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
  @media only screen and (max-device-width:480px; ) {
    body .header { width:300px}
  }
</style>

<body>
  <img src="http://www.url.com/image.jpg" class="header" width="600px" height="100px" />
</body>
```

This forces the image width to 600px, since the element style overwrites the regular style set.